# Recognizing bridgeless cubic graph with special 2-factor

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

A 2-factor of graph $G(V, E)$ is a set of vertex-disjoint cycles that cover $V$. It is [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen's_theorem) that every connected bridgeless cubic graph contains a 2-factor (and a perfect matching).

I conjecture that it is hard to recognize bridgeless cubic graphs when restricting cycles lengths in the 2-factor. I conjecture that it is $NP$-complete to decide the existence of restricted 2-factor in a bridgeless cubic graph.

**Restricted 2-factor problem**:

**Input**: connected bridgeless cubic graph.

**Output**: Decide whether there is a 2-factor such that lengths of the disjoint-cycles of the 2-factor form a proper non-empty subset of $N=\{5, 6, 7, ..., |V|\}$.

In general graphs,  [Papadimitriou](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X80900023) showed that deciding the existence of $C_k$-free 2-factor is $NP$-complete when $k \ge 5$  (A 2-factor is $C_k$-free if it contains no cycles of length $k$ or less). Deciding the existence of $C_4$-free 2-factor is an open problem.

> Is this a known result? Or is there a counter-example to this conjecture?

A counter-example is a polynomial-time algorithm to solve the decision problem when the lengths of the 2-factor cycles form a proper non-empty subset of $N=\{5, 6, 7, ..., |V| \}$.

Comment: Do you know anything about the same problem for $C_3$-free factors?

Comment: No, I am not aware of such result.